# Unable to connect two ubuntu systems

Tags: automount

I just got my new ThinkPad X121e and installed Ubuntu 11.10 ..everything is fine, except I can't get my data from my old EeePC (Ubuntu 10.4) to my new baby. The EeePC says it could not mount Ubuntu 11.10 i386 because:

```
Error mounting: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
/dev/loop0,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error

(could this be the IDE device where you in fact use
ide-scsi so that sr0 or sda or so is needed?)
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so
```

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks!!
Lisa

Answer (score 1):

What command are you using?

For me this error occures e.g. due to an typo:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 /Desktop/test.iso /media/iso -o loop
```

If I run the command with "~" everything is fine:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 ~/Desktop/test.iso /media/iso -o loop
```